# C/C library to convert SVG to raster.

Tags: c++, c, svg, rasterizing

Does anybody knows some free or not free library for converting svg to raster image (preferably to png).

I see that there are ImageMagic, GraphicMagic, librsvg. But I can't to figure out how to use them or are suitable to my issue. I need to do trasformation programmatically from my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical library to render SVG is [librsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/).

You may want to check that out.

try this [link](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngcode.html) ...

its very use full to you..

Comment: I see that librsvg is so cool but there no documentation on how to use it.

As I can see there are in your "link" there are specified only utilities

Comment: check this [link](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html)    here is manual .go through that and try solve your problem .

Comment: @dmigous: I assume you already visited its homepage and its [API docs](http://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/).

Comment: I had looked at that. But nothing useful there at least about can I do this trasformation or not.

Comment: What's the problem ? Documentation says for example that you can render svg to cairo surface. Next you will use cairo `surface.write_to_png`. You can render svg into other buffers - such as GTK+ buffers [and etc](http://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/2.36/rsvg.html).

Comment: and how to compile or where to get compiled librsvg for windows?